# Vbscript trying to copy files. Getting required object errors

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a script that will copy a file when the user gives a prompted folder they wish to move it to. I've tried different ways from multiple different posts on this site and each time I try to fix it I either get FileObject System as a required object or just a ".

What am I doing wrong and can someone help me fix this?

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim FileSystemObject
Dim oFolder
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0,"Select a Folder",0,0)
Dim WshShell, strCurDir
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCurDir   = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
FileSystemObject.CopyFile strCurDir & "test.txt", oFolder
```

Comment: the variable FileSystemObject is never assigned a value. I believe you want to use objFSO on the last line, since you actually set it to somthing.

Comment: @Frank Thomas I  thought that the Set used it? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: I don't see a line that sets the variable named FileSystemObject, which you reference on the last line. Also, you set the variable objFSO to a filesystem object, but then never use that variable to do anything. you should be able to fix it by changing the last line to  `objFSO.CopyFile strCurDir & "test.txt", oFolder`, and then deleting line 4.

Comment: @Frank Thomas I tried that and it doesn't do anything. It just says "File not found" even though it's right there... It gives code 800A0035

Comment: print out strCurDir. I'm guessing its not pointing where you think it is. it may be easiest to use a message box to display the variable value, since im not sure how you are invoking the script: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_dialog_boxes.htm

Comment: @Frank Thomas I'm probably just going to switch to batch. I tried it with message box and it still gave that error. I only need the script so the user can move the main program they'd be using to another spot and rename it if they want. I wanted to make a program that'd help people going through abusive situations find help, but I can't figure out how to make it easy for the user to move the program to a location where it could be hidden from a potential abuser. Thank you for the help though and have a wonderful day!

Comment: i recommend powershell. its default on windows now, and can do things like work with directory selection widgets. good luck.

Comment: @Frank Thomas Does the user need to install anything? Also thank you!

Comment: nope, powershell is built in for any windows since vista.

Comment: @Frank Thomas Oh ok. Thank you! Have a good day/night!